# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable, is it ()?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

my code is as follows, I ran it for the past few days without an issue, but this morning I get this error, when I freshly open the code and run it once fully there anr no issues, then I change nothing but run a second time, and I get the error after any cell that calls this Phase_Extractor function

```
def Phase_Extractor(fpath):

n = 1 #air refractive index
wvl = 632E-9


displacement = []
phase = []

tdms_file1 = TdmsFile.read(fpath)
for group in tdms_file1.groups():
    groupname = group.name
    for channel in group.channels():
        channel_name = channel.name
        # Access dictionary of properties:
        properties = channel.properties
        # Access numpy array of data for channel:
        velocity_volts1 = channel[:]
        # Access a subset of data
        data_subset = channel[0:100]
        
velocity = velocity_volts1/1000 ########## ###################Convert from volts to m/s ################################

time = np.arange(0,5,0.000005) 

displacement = scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(velocity, time) ################ convert to displacement from velocity #########

for i in range(0, len(displacement)):
    phase.append(((2*np.pi*n*displacement[i]))/wvl) ############# Convert to phase ################################
    
phase = np.append(phase, phase[0-1]) ################### make phase list same size as time step list ###################  
    

return phase
```

I know this usually something to do with [] vs (). but can't see where. The error message is :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
Input In [38], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 MDP500Full = MinPhaseFinder(r"\Users\seanl\Documents\Master 
Thesis\500HzFullvol Converted.tdms", 500)
  2 MDP500Half = MinPhaseFinder(r"\Users\seanl\Documents\Master 
Thesis\500HzHalfvol Converted.tdms", 500)
  3 MDP500Quarter = MinPhaseFinder(r"\Users\seanl\Documents\Master 
Thesis\500HzQuartervol Converted.tdms", 500)

Input In [26], in MinPhaseFinder(fpath, sf)
      1 def MinPhaseFinder(fpath, sf):
----> 3     filtered_phase = 
butter_highpass_filter(Phase_Extractor(fpath), 7 , 20000)
      5     X = fft(filtered_phase)
      6     sr = 200E3

Input In [11], in Phase_Extractor(fpath)
     26 time = np.arange(0,5,0.000005) 
     28 displacement = scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(velocity, time) 
################ convert to displacement from velocity #########
---> 30 for i in range(0, len(displacement)):
     31     phase.append(((2*np.pi*n*displacement[i]))/wvl) 
############# Convert to phase ################################
     33 phase = np.append(phase, phase[0-1]) ################### make 
phase list same size as time step list ###################  

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok, so another bit of info, when I freshly open my script and run everything from top to bottom, there are no issues. but then the second time I run, without changing anything, the error occurs if I run a cell calling the specific method that pops the error. Is this a memory or server thing?

Comment: You appear to have assigned something to `range` or `len`. Don't do that.

Comment: Please add the error message. It would be very hard to debug otherwise

Comment: The error message is added

Comment: @user2357112 yes that was the issue thank you!